# How do I run parallel test in bitbucket through multiple machines?

Tags: automation, jira, cypress, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm currently using cypress to be able to run my test through a bitbucket pipeline, and it seems that I cannot find a way to run those tests through multiple machines, and I can't find any documentation that will explain how to do it.

However, I would like to know if it is possible by using bitbucket, or if I have to start using any other CI.

Does someone have the same issue or the same experience?

Comment: Have you seen this https://bitbucket.org/cypress-io/cypress-example-kitchensink/src/master/bitbucket-pipelines.yml ?

Comment: Yes, I saw that link. My test is running in parallel and it seems that is running well. Now, I would like to use some Nodes to be able to set up my test through multiple computers